# Build is successful with Heroku but an application error

Tags: html, reactjs, heroku, webpack, redux

Allow me to explain. I use Heroku for enabling my online application (React/Redux).

So, my build has been done correctly, but when I viewed the `log` I found this error:

`at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=desolate-river-47144.herokuapp.com request_id=334501ef-1403-4ba3-a69e-3587b44dd79c fwd="xx.xxx.xx.xx" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https`

(*fwd* contains my IP address)

I only have this error. I tried `heroku restart`, but the problem remained.

All of my logs are as follows. As you see, all has been built – that's what I don't understand.

`2018-05-20T17:06:13.022497+00:00 app[web.1]:   [192] ./~/react-redux/~/lodash/_getRawTag.js 1.14 kB {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.022494+00:00 app[web.1]:   [190] ./~/react-redux/~/lodash/_root.js 300 bytes {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.022499+00:00 app[web.1]:   [193] ./~/react-redux/~/lodash/_objectToString.js 565 bytes {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.022501+00:00 app[web.1]:   [194] ./~/react-redux/~/lodash/_getPrototype.js 163 bytes {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.022502+00:00 app[web.1]:   [195] ./~/react-redux/~/lodash/_overArg.js 382 bytes {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.022504+00:00 app[web.1]:   [196] ./~/react-redux/~/lodash/isObjectLike.js 614 bytes {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.022506+00:00 app[web.1]:   [197] ./~/react-redux/~/hoist-non-react-statics/index.js 1.39 kB {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.022507+00:00 app[web.1]:   [198] ./~/invariant/browser.js 1.4 kB {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.022509+00:00 app[web.1]:   [199] ./src/routes.js 3.13 kB {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.022510+00:00 app[web.1]:   [200] ./~/react-router-dom/index.js 2.17 kB {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.022512+00:00 app[web.1]:   [201] ./~/react-router-dom/BrowserRouter.js 2.98 kB {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.022513+00:00 app[web.1]:   [202] ./~/warning/browser.js 1.81 kB {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.022515+00:00 app[web.1]:   [203] ./~/prop-types/index.js 956 bytes {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.022517+00:00 app[web.1]:   [204] ./~/prop-types/factoryWithTypeCheckers.js 19.8 kB {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.022518+00:00 app[web.1]:   [205] ./~/fbjs/lib/emptyFunction.js 959 bytes {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.022520+00:00 app[web.1]:   [206] ./~/fbjs/lib/invariant.js 1.51 kB {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.022521+00:00 app[web.1]:   [207] ./~/fbjs/lib/warning.js 1.9 kB {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.022523+00:00 app[web.1]:   [208] ./~/object-assign/index.js 2.11 kB {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.022525+00:00 app[web.1]:   [209] ./~/prop-types/lib/ReactPropTypesSecret.js 314 bytes {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.022526+00:00 app[web.1]:   [210] ./~/prop-types/checkPropTypes.js 2.87 kB {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.022528+00:00 app[web.1]:   [211] ./~/prop-types/factoryWithThrowingShims.js 1.49 kB {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.022530+00:00 app[web.1]:   [212] ./~/history/createBrowserHistory.js 9.75 kB {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.022531+00:00 app[web.1]:   [213] ./~/history/LocationUtils.js 2.65 kB {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.022533+00:00 app[web.1]:   [214] ./~/resolve-pathname/cjs/index.js 1.88 kB {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.022534+00:00 app[web.1]:   [215] ./~/value-equal/cjs/index.js 1.22 kB {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.022536+00:00 app[web.1]:   [216] ./~/history/PathUtils.js 1.77 kB {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.022538+00:00 app[web.1]:   [217] ./~/history/createTransitionManager.js 2.36 kB {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.022539+00:00 app[web.1]:   [218] ./~/history/DOMUtils.js 2.49 kB {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.022541+00:00 app[web.1]:   [219] ./~/react-router-dom/Router.js 334 bytes {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.022543+00:00 app[web.1]:   [220] ./~/react-router/Router.js 4.27 kB {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.022544+00:00 app[web.1]:   [221] ./~/react-router-dom/HashRouter.js 2.93 kB {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.022546+00:00 app[web.1]:   [222] ./~/history/createHashHistory.js 10.1 kB {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.022547+00:00 app[web.1]:   [223] ./~/react-router-dom/Link.js 4.56 kB {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.022549+00:00 app[web.1]:   [224] ./~/react-router-dom/MemoryRouter.js 364 bytes {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.022550+00:00 app[web.1]:   [225] ./~/react-router/MemoryRouter.js 2.98 kB {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.022552+00:00 app[web.1]:   [226] ./~/history/createMemoryHistory.js 5.82 kB {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.022553+00:00 app[web.1]:   [227] ./~/react-router-dom/NavLink.js 3.16 kB {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.022555+00:00 app[web.1]:   [228] ./~/react-router-dom/Route.js 329 bytes {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.022556+00:00 app[web.1]:   [229] ./~/react-router/Route.js 6.76 kB {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.022558+00:00 app[web.1]:   [230] ./~/react-router/matchPath.js 2.27 kB {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.022560+00:00 app[web.1]:   [231] ./~/path-to-regexp/index.js 10.8 kB {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.022561+00:00 app[web.1]:   [232] ./~/isarray/index.js 120 bytes {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.022563+00:00 app[web.1]:   [233] ./~/react-router-dom/Prompt.js 334 bytes {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.022564+00:00 app[web.1]:   [234] ./~/react-router/Prompt.js 3.09 kB {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.022566+00:00 app[web.1]:   [235] ./~/react-router-dom/Redirect.js 344 bytes {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.022568+00:00 app[web.1]:   [236] ./~/react-router/Redirect.js 3.65 kB {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.022570+00:00 app[web.1]:   [237] ./~/history/index.js 1.58 kB {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.022571+00:00 app[web.1]:   [238] ./~/react-router-dom/StaticRouter.js 364 bytes {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.022573+00:00 app[web.1]:   [239] ./~/react-router/StaticRouter.js 6.92 kB {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.022575+00:00 app[web.1]:   [240] ./~/react-router-dom/Switch.js 334 bytes {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.022576+00:00 app[web.1]:   [241] ./~/react-router/Switch.js 3.86 kB {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.022578+00:00 app[web.1]:   [242] ./~/react-router-dom/matchPath.js 349 bytes {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.022580+00:00 app[web.1]:   [243] ./~/react-router-dom/withRouter.js 354 bytes {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.022581+00:00 app[web.1]:   [244] ./~/react-router/withRouter.js 1.86 kB {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.022583+00:00 app[web.1]:   [245] ./~/hoist-non-react-statics/index.js 2.6 kB {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.022584+00:00 app[web.1]:   [246] ./src/components/Posts.js 4.52 kB {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.022586+00:00 app[web.1]:   [247] ./src/actions/index.js 1.24 kB {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.022588+00:00 app[web.1]:   [248] ./src/actions/actions-type.js 338 bytes {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.022589+00:00 app[web.1]:   [249] ./~/axios/index.js 40 bytes {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.022591+00:00 app[web.1]:   [250] ./~/axios/lib/axios.js 1.37 kB {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.022592+00:00 app[web.1]:   [251] ./~/axios/lib/utils.js 7.54 kB {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.022594+00:00 app[web.1]:   [252] ./~/axios/lib/helpers/bind.js 256 bytes {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.022596+00:00 app[web.1]:   [253] ./~/is-buffer/index.js 698 bytes {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.022597+00:00 app[web.1]:   [254] ./~/axios/lib/core/Axios.js 2.19 kB {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.022599+00:00 app[web.1]:   [255] ./~/axios/lib/defaults.js 2.43 kB {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.022606+00:00 app[web.1]:   [256] ./~/axios/lib/helpers/normalizeHeaderName.js 357 bytes {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.022608+00:00 app[web.1]:   [257] ./~/axios/lib/adapters/xhr.js 6.17 kB {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.022610+00:00 app[web.1]:   [258] ./~/axios/lib/core/settle.js 757 bytes {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.022612+00:00 app[web.1]:   [259] ./~/axios/lib/core/createError.js 625 bytes {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.022613+00:00 app[web.1]:   [260] ./~/axios/lib/core/enhanceError.js 592 bytes {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.022615+00:00 app[web.1]:   [261] ./~/axios/lib/helpers/buildURL.js 1.55 kB {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.022617+00:00 app[web.1]:   [262] ./~/axios/lib/helpers/parseHeaders.js 1.39 kB {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.022619+00:00 app[web.1]:   [263] ./~/axios/lib/helpers/isURLSameOrigin.js 2.25 kB {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.022620+00:00 app[web.1]:   [264] ./~/axios/lib/helpers/btoa.js 986 bytes {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.022622+00:00 app[web.1]:   [265] ./~/axios/lib/helpers/cookies.js 1.36 kB {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.022624+00:00 app[web.1]:   [266] ./~/axios/lib/core/InterceptorManager.js 1.25 kB {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.022625+00:00 app[web.1]:   [267] ./~/axios/lib/core/dispatchRequest.js 2.2 kB {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.022627+00:00 app[web.1]:   [268] ./~/axios/lib/core/transformData.js 550 bytes {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.022629+00:00 app[web.1]:   [269] ./~/axios/lib/cancel/isCancel.js 102 bytes {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.022631+00:00 app[web.1]:   [270] ./~/axios/lib/helpers/isAbsoluteURL.js 563 bytes {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.022632+00:00 app[web.1]:   [271] ./~/axios/lib/helpers/combineURLs.js 380 bytes {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.022634+00:00 app[web.1]:   [272] ./~/axios/lib/cancel/Cancel.js 385 bytes {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.022636+00:00 app[web.1]:   [273] ./~/axios/lib/cancel/CancelToken.js 1.24 kB {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.022637+00:00 app[web.1]:   [274] ./~/axios/lib/helpers/spread.js 564 bytes {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.022639+00:00 app[web.1]:   [275] ./src/components/Post.js 3.39 kB {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.022640+00:00 app[web.1]:   [276] ./src/components/RouteNotFound.js 2.42 kB {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.022642+00:00 app[web.1]:   [277] ./src/reducers/index.js 608 bytes {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.022643+00:00 app[web.1]:   [278] ./src/reducers/Posts-reducer.js 703 bytes {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.022645+00:00 app[web.1]:   [279] ./src/reducers/activePost-reducer.js 418 bytes {0} [built]
2018-05-20T17:06:13.023213+00:00 app[web.1]: webpack: Compiled successfully.
2018-05-20T17:06:46.501296+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H20 desc="App boot timeout" method=GET path="/" host=desolate-river-47144.herokuapp.com request_id=e8a9dd79-4bce-4701-ba86-59b43014372f fwd="77.144.48.66" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-05-20T17:07:06.721306+00:00 app[web.1]: Error waiting for process to terminate: No child processes
2018-05-20T17:07:06.686809+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2018-05-20T17:07:06.687045+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2018-05-20T17:07:06.819749+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 22
2018-05-20T17:07:07.316344+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2018-05-20T17:07:10.468356+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=desolate-river-47144.herokuapp.com request_id=42afaab0-f2ca-4c14-bfab-8b364bb5b7fb fwd="77.144.48.66" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-05-20T17:07:12.928299+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=desolate-river-47144.herokuapp.com request_id=b1b60a3d-dcd6-47b0-be36-5e46e078b5e8 fwd="77.144.48.66" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-05-20T17:07:24.422621+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=desolate-river-47144.herokuapp.com request_id=c90f89dd-3c73-4086-87bb-62758b4f0698 fwd="77.144.48.66" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-05-20T17:07:25.323510+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=desolate-river-47144.herokuapp.com request_id=374cc4d9-f87d-471a-a6c6-071e8664476b fwd="77.144.48.66" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https`

Comment: Do you have any of the log lines before this? The error from the perspective of the program is usually found before this. This looks like it's from heroku[router], but the more important error usually starts with a different tag.

Comment: @QuinnMortimer I edited my post with all my logs :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess is that your server is not listening on the port Heroku expects it to listen on.

These two log lines are what suggest that this might be the case to me, especially because before the first line there's about a 30 second gap since the process last logged anything.

`2018-05-20T17:06:46.501296+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H20 desc="App boot timeout" method=GET path="/" host=desolate-river-47144.herokuapp.com request_id=e8a9dd79-4bce-4701-ba86-59b43014372f fwd="77.144.48.66" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https`

`2018-05-20T17:07:06.686809+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch`

Wherever you set the port your server listens, try doing something like `const port = process.env.PORT || 3000`